# clipboard Listener event is being called twice

Tags: c#, clipboard

i want to save the changes in my clipboard. so i registered my application to get all the changes that happens to the Clipboard.

Using

```
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    protected static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(int hwnd);
```

and then

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
                OnClipboardChanged();
                break;
             ...
        }
     }

private void OnClipboardChanged()
{
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
        {
         MessageBox.Show(Clipboard.GetText().ToString());
        }
}
```

The Problem is:
When copying text from an application like visual studio or firefox, the OnClipboardChanged() function will be called twice or 3 times sometimes.

I think that those application will write the Data to the clipboard with different formats, this is why the function is called more than once.
But how would i prevent saving the same data because OnClipboardChanged() is being called more than once ?

Comment: Is there a property on the Message (m) parameter that will be the same for each instance of writing to the clipboard? Perhaps an ID? If so, maybe you could ignore the message if you've already processed that message/ID?

Comment: Hi Bob,
I can`t find anything about msg id or something like that..this is a real good idea, and would be cool if every msg has a "call id" thanks anyway

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because they're opening/closing the clipboard multiple times.  I've seen such madness before. Excel used to perform 24 separate operations when copying a chart.
Instead of this (pseudocode):

```
openClipboard
for each format {
  place data on clipboard(format)
}
closeClipboard
```

they're probably doing this:

```
for each format {
  openClipboard
  place data on clipboard(format)
  closeClipboard
}
```

Update: The usual mitigation strategy is to avoid reacting to every update, and react to the LAST update after a reasonable "settle time" has elapsed with no further clipboard notifications.  500ms will usually be more than adequate.

Comment: Hi ..thanks for your answer ...how would i make sure that i get the function called only once ? how would i check if the data in the clipboard didn`t change, but has been rewritten like you said above ?

I just want to save html if it is available, if not i need to get the text ..but rewriting the clipboard as you mentioned is calling the function twice or even 3 times sometimes, so i cant decide if i have to save the data present in the clipboard or not !?

Comment: The even handler will be called once for each clipboard update (WM_DrawClipboard message, typically).  The only way to have it called once, would be to correct the program that's performing the updates, and that's beyond your control.  See my update above for mitigation strategy.

Comment: Thank chris ..i will accept your answer as it seems the only way it could be done ...thanks for the idea..

Comment: WM_DrawClipboard event is behaving incorrectly. Don`t use that.

Answer (score 1):

**Prevent multiple calls to the clipboard**

```
private int _i = 0;
private int i
{
    get
    {
        async void setI()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(20);
                i = 0;
            }
            );
        }
        setI();
        return _i;
    }
    set
    {
        _i = value;
    }
}
private IntPtr HwndHandler(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE)
    {
        if(i<1)
        {
            this.ClipboardUpdate?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            i++;
        }
    }
    handled = false;
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, but all posts to stack overflow are required to be in English. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/) for details.