# How to not get unnecessary clipboard update in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

I'm making a WPF application that monitors every change in the clipboard. To do so I registered my window as a clipboard format listener.

**My problem is like this**: I'm copying a file in the File Explorer and I'm receiving a notification that the clipboard has changed (of course this is what I want) but **when I close** the File Explorer window with the file I copied I'm again receiving the notification. How to prevent receiving this notification?

Here is my Win32 class:

```
internal const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);
```

Here is my method of registering the window and the method for receiving notifications that the clipboard has changed.

```
private void _AddClipboardFormatListener()
{
    WindowInteropHelper wih = new WindowInteropHelper(_window);

    hWndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(wih.EnsureHandle());
    hWndSource.AddHook(WndProc);

    Win32.AddClipboardFormatListener(hWndSource.Handle);
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        //Here I get the unnecessary update.
        case Win32.WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:

            //Invoke event that the clipboard has changed.
            break;
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Comment: This is common. Applications can open/set the ClipBoard multiple times. Office programs also set the clipboard on close (scrubbing OLE objects and other stuff that will be invalid afterwards). You have to check whether you have duplicate object data (hashing can be good here). It depends on how deep you want to go. Tampering with the DataObject to *insert* your own data formats as *identifiers* is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is looking for more information about that problem I just found that question, hope it helps -[clipboard Listener event is being called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10373713/8454410)